# Cancel button is not working in Azure B2C Sign up policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

From mobile app, authorize endpoint is invoked and loaded in webview.
When cancel button is pressed, It does not go back to APP(redirect URI).

It works for Web app client where it returns to web app with error code.
Help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Is this a built-in policy or a custom policy? Also, do you have any client side JS or customization?